# Protractor methods insisting element they're being called on is not defined

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a protractor test and for some weird reason protractor is telling me that elements which test as being present are undefined when I try to use protractor methods on them like `.get(1)` or `.by.xpath('..')`.

Please let me know what information is needed to debug this issue.

Comment: Could you show the complete test code you have and the error traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a bad assumption and now realize that the get method does not go through the children but rather all results from given query.

Instead what I needed what element(by.css('css')).element(by.css('css')).